# Single AEM JCR package for multi-module project

Tags: maven, aem, jcr, multi-module

I have an AEM project organized similarly to [Adobe's core components project](https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/aem-core-wcm-components), in which the `all` module is in charge of building the zip that contains an embedded .jar of the bundle (`core`), and two subpackaged .zip `content-package`s (`content` and `config`).

When uploaded and installed to AEM via package manager, the single zip created in `all/target` explodes to its 3 subpackages (`core`, `content`, and `config`). I want to create a single zip that keeps my project's footprint as a **single package in AEM** package manager.

Here is the relevant bits of my `all/pom.xml` (same as Adobe's core components [`all/pom.xml`](https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/aem-core-wcm-components/blob/master/all/pom.xml)):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.day.jcr.vault</groupId>
    <artifactId>content-package-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
        <verbose>true</verbose>
        <group>myApp</group>
        <failOnError>true</failOnError>
        <builtContentDirectory>target/${project.artifactId}</builtContentDirectory>
        <embeddeds>
            <embedded>
                <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                <artifactId>myApp.core</artifactId>
                <target>/apps/myApp/install</target>
                <filter>true</filter>
            </embedded>
        </embeddeds>
        <failOnMissingEmbed>true</failOnMissingEmbed>
        <subPackages>
            <subPackage>
                <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                <artifactId>myApp.content</artifactId>
                <filter>true</filter>
            </subPackage>
            <subPackage>
                <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                <artifactId>myApp.config</artifactId>
                <filter>true</filter>
            </subPackage>
        </subPackages>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

---

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>myApp.core</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>myApp.content</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
        <type>zip</type>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>myApp.config</artifactId>
        <type>zip</type>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Why would you do that? Just to have a different setup than everyone else? Apart from that, if you want *one* package, put it all in one module . But I don't think this will work for the Java part at all. The java part is build as an OSGi bundle, the rest is build as CQ packages.

Comment: It came in as a 'requirement'. I'm perfectly fine saying that this isn't something we can/should do, just want to then make sure it's not possible. @OliverGebert

Comment: Even if you should find a way I would never ever recommend to use that way of packaging. In the standard way, your apps package includes the OSGi-bundle that lies in a /apps/.../install folder. Those folders are watched by the app and as soon as a OSGi bundle is added/modified/deleted, it will be installed/updated/uninstalled in the OSGi container as well. Bringing config and content (or apps) into one project is ok, but in the end this might lead to problems as content does usually contain initial content or test content which you might not want to deploy to PROD with every new release.